# I am an immortal warlord - how do I spread my DNA all over the world?

Tags: warfare, humans, reproduction, sex

I am the emperor Haghonon the great; my kingdom is unmatched at war thanks to our giant wolves.

I have all supplies that I need to take over the world, but that goal is simple for my army.

My real plan is to spread my seed all over the world - **How can I fulfill my goal?**

Time is my friend not my enemy.

Comment: There is a real history that does not involve immortality - ask Genghis Khan.  http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/gnxp/2010/08/1-in-200-men-direct-descendants-of-genghis-khan/

Comment: Why do you particularly want to spread your DNA?  If you just maintain a large harem (with a changing membership), the DNA-spreading gets done automatically.

Answer (score 12):

**Nothing to it**

Since time is your ally, make like [Genghis Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genghis_Khan) whom apparently [.5%](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/gnxp/2010/08/1-in-200-men-direct-descendants-of-genghis-khan/#.WNx1EDvythE) of the human population is directly descended from.

**Instructions for spreading you seed across the earth:**

**Step 1:** 
Conquer a region of the earth. Eliminate competing gene pool, which should occur during the conquering. The [Mongols](http://www.history.com/topics/genghis-khan) only conquered 12 million square miles, and they slaughtered those that opposed them.

**Step 2:** 
Get very busy and enjoy the spoils of victory.

**Step 3:**
Repeat as necessary. Use army of wolves to keep your many wives from killing you. Exponential growth will do the rest. *Keep tabs on your daughters to avoid inbreeding*

**Step 4:** 
Encourage widespread immigration of descendants to maintain healthy genetic diversity.

***Unless you mean literally spreading your seed across the earth***

Comment: Great great great great great great great grandpa Genghis certainly got around. Isn't that right cousin?

Comment: This is a great *start* for an answer. But as of now any information that explains *how to actually do it* is only available by following through the links to other websites that are not guaranteed to stay online. Please take the time and quote or even paraphrase the linked information. Thanks.

Comment: As @dot_Sp0T said this is currently basically a link-only-answer. Please try to summarize the content of the links so that readers of your answer will know what you are talking about even if the links go out-of-date and without the need of external research. Links should provide additional information for interested users.

Comment: Still woking on finding the median between too little info and doing all the work.

Comment: Finding the right balance is hard, but this looks good to me. +1 Especially for "Keep tabs on your daughters to avoid inbreeding" and "Unless you mean literally spreading your seed across the earth"

Answer (score 2):

like what Joe Kissling said, Gengkhis Khan's DNA is in .5% of the human population, how? he gets his henchmen/army gather women from his lands; If you want the "Seeding" progress to get faster; simply kill off anyone insignificant who doesn't have your DNA.

**now for the medical side,** 
DNA does not get passed down fully, after a few generations; your DNA will contribute less to the gene pool, if you want EVERYONE to have at least 25% of your DNA (after 2 generations), you would need to do the "Purge" and plant your "Seed" every two generations.
**The problem** is that having parents that have similar DNA (basically incest) would lead to a greater chance of a defective offspring.

I would recommend "Emperor Haghonon The Great" to "Purge" and "Seed" every 3 generations (about 100 years give and take, assuming the average lifespan is 75 years) making everyone 12.5% related to you.

P.S you would name this event to your people the "Purge", sound cool enough.

Comment: a hint: 3 generations is approx. 75 years. You need to consder the timespan from birth to reproduction, not to death, for the time between two generations.

Comment: Just finished an edit that included quite a bit of what you said.

Comment: @JoeKissling thanks for the inclusion, giving some credit is appreciated~

Answer (score 1):

Take your time. Fertilize women in your conquered territories. Make sure many of their male children can migrate to the rest of the world. Marry off your cast-off women and encourage their spouses to embrace any children sired by your imperial self.

If Genghis Khan can spread his genes until 5% of the human population carry them in one generation, what can an immortal emperor do if he continues a similar program over centuries? Consider this is now a millennium after his gene-spreading activities, so if your gene-spreading is carried on without surcease then they will be disseminated on a massive scale. Presumably eventually every person on the planet will carry some of your genes.

Do what Genghis Khan did, and keep on doing it -- forever and a day. Then your genes will flood the gene pool.

Answer (score 0):

Make like King Herod and re-enact the [Massacre of the Innocents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_of_the_Innocents) on a global scale.

Deny any child be born that doesn't carry your bloodline.

I'm not sure even your army of wolves will be able to withstand the backlash from the population to your program of worldwide child genocide though.

Comment: Program or pogrom?